# How to route traffic with if condition based on source IP addresses in NGINX Ingress Controllers

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx, routes, nginx-ingress

I have deployed a simple application in two Kubernetes clusters. The clusters reside in EU and US regions. The users must connect to the service through abc.com (Example) URL. The users/requests are coming from our internal network. The source IP address ranges are known. How can we route to the correct cluster based on the source IP ranges? For example requests coming from IP range 10.0.0.0/16 should route to the EU kubernetes cluster. What solution is the most suitable for this? We're using Azure and I tried Azure Traffic Manager. But it only works with public endpoints. So it doesn't suit our scenario. Can we add an 'if' condition based on the source IP ranges in the Ingress rules and route traffic to the correct Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: you can use Traffic Manager for internal routing, too. You just can't use the health checks.

Comment: @silent But where in Microsoft documentation it has mentioned about that? Can you link some docs about that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring?branch=main#always-serve

Comment: @silent So in my case I'm using Geo-Based routing Azure Traffic Manager. So if we're using Internal IPs how does Azure TM identify the IPs of those internal IPs geo location?

Comment: how about subnet-based routing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#subnet-traffic-routing-method

Comment: Oh nice! It will still work with internal IPs right? So I already know my source IP (Internal) ranges. I will go with Subnet-Based routing. Also I will accept your solution if you could add it as an answer for my question. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed in the comments:

You can use Traffic Manager also for internal endpoints, you just can't use health probing for them. Use [Always serve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring?branch=main#always-serve) for this scenario.

Also, you should be able to use [subnet-based routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#subnet-traffic-routing-method).

Comment: Hi once again. I created a test VM inside Azure. It has a private IP address of 10.112.3.196 So I created Azure TM with Subnet-Based routing enabled. Created a new Endpoint (Type: External endpoint) and gave the private IP address of our NGINX ingress controller as the target IP. Disabled the health checks also. I login to my VM and did nslookup abc.def and the answer was "Can't find abc.def: No answer"

Comment: Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: I assume abc.def is something like "my.trafficmanager.net"? have you tested dns resolution using something like https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ ?

Comment: I have an alias record in Azure DNS for abc.def which points to the traffic manager URL. So abc.def -> my.trafficmanager.net There's no A record for abc.def anywhere. Our app runs inside AKS. I have created the ingress for abc.def So do I need to still create an A record for abc.def?

Comment: What I have done is: I have just added the NGINX ingress controller IP address as the target to the TM endpoint

Comment: Any other additional config to be done here?